# Facebook Invalid redirect_URI

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

We have Facebook canvas app and Signin using Facebook buttons which works perfectly fine when opened from desktop, but same doesnt work when opened from App center of Facebook Android app.

While exchanging code for oauth token sent by Facebook i always get Bad request and error message says invalid redirect_uri. But i cross checked Mobile Website URL and it exactly matches with Secure Canvas URL. Any one having idea why this error?

I read few forums to exclude trailing slash, but these didnt work for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please add more information, like the exact error messages you are getting? Thanks and have a great day!

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur reply, I am using spring social to connect with Facebook, 
Stacktrace shows this message 
POST request for "https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/oauth/access_token" resulted in 400 (Bad Request);

Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request"

Comment: Hi Root, from the information you supply, you are using graph api 1.0, which would be not supported in next month. So please upgrade to 2.x as soon as possible.